# How to Import Java Library and use It In my IOS(Swift) Project, Xcode 9

Tags: java, android, ios, swift3, j2objc

We have a Common Java Library for to be use in both Android and IOS .. In Android It Is common But When It Comes to IOS is there any way to use Java Library In my project.. Please help If you have any Ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Google's tool [J2ObjC](https://github.com/google/j2objc). Basically it translates Java to iOS Objective-C.

Comment: But if do that .. do I Have to use Obj-C Bridge Header to use in Swift?

Comment: Yes, if you translates your Java library to Objective-C, you will need to use the Obj-C Bridge Header to use it in Swift.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a java library in a swift application, but you can use a java to swift converter to convert your java library to a swift library.